# How to deal with spaces in filenames

Tags: c#, io

I am trying to iterate over files in a local directory:

```
foreach (string name in Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(path))
{
    FileAttrtibutes att = File.GetAttributes(name)
}
```

One of the files in the folder at `path` is named "This is a test".  `GetAttributes()` throws an exception on filenames with spaces.

Apart from replacing spaces with some other character, how should I handle spaces in filenames in this circumstance?

I apologise.  I was a bit hasty.  Let me redefine the problem, even though I now have a workaround at least.

This snippet of code shows the problem:

```
Uri u = new Uri(@"file:///c:/test/This is a test");
FileAttributes a = File.GetAttributes(u.AbsolutePath);
```

File.GetAttributes throws a System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'c:\test\This%20is%20a%20test'.  'c:\test\This is a test' exists.

So it seems Uri.AbsolutePath is inserting %20 for space, and I can just do a string replace to get my code working.  I don't know that I should expect to have to do the replace, but at least I can get it working.  Any other ideas welcome.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `File.GetAttributes(@"C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\This is a test.txt");` works perfectly fine here. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? (Without the loop, just a single line that throws an exception.)

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: Saying it throws a exception is not helpful. Giving information about the exception does.

Comment: If I replicate your code into a console application everything works fine. What's the exceptiontype and -message?

Comment: Does you file has the extension?

Comment: @Andrew he is looping through files in a directory, wether there is a extension is irrelevant.

Comment: yes and he uses `File.GetAttributes` for each single entry

Comment: And he says it throws an exception on that specific file. So he must of stepped through the code to see where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: You need to unescape the Uri path - to put the %20's back to spaces

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getattributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) these are the possible exceptions,

**ArgumentException**
path is empty, contains only white spaces, or contains invalid characters.

**PathTooLongException**
The specified path, file name, or both exceed the system-defined maximum length. For example, on Windows-based platforms, paths must be less than 248 characters, and file names must be less than 260 characters.

**NotSupportedException**
path is in an invalid format.

**FileNotFoundException**
path represents a file and is invalid, such as being on an unmapped drive, or the file cannot be found.

**DirectoryNotFoundException**
path represents a directory and is invalid, such as being on an unmapped drive, or the directory cannot be found.

**IOException**
This file is being used by another process.

**UnauthorizedAccessException**
The caller does not have the required permission.

Since you are looping through entries in a directory, the only guess i could make without you telling us the exception, is that either the file is being used by another process or your app doesn't have permission to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered a similar problem.

That's my stupid solution: Just add `.Replace("%20", " ")`

```
var assemblyPath = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath.Replace("%20", " ");
```