# BASH Scripts - How to deal with spaces in data file names

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script I am trying to write to move customer files to a backup server.  Because these are customer files, I have no control on how they are named.  We need to be able to offload these to a backup server before we process them, but so far the script has issues handling any directory or file dropped in that has spaces in the name.  I think it may be the way things are quoted in the script, or it may be something else, but I can't figure it out.  I found several promising leads including:

[How to deal with spaces in filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23237924/how-to-deal-with-spaces-in-filenames)

[How to deal with file name starts with spaces in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948608/how-to-deal-with-file-name-starts-with-spaces-in-bash)

However, going through all these and several other sources I have not been able to determine how to get it to work properly.  The code is:

```
#! /bin/bash
# Get customer to search
CUSTOMER=$1
# Get destination
DESTINATION_FOLDER=$2
# Get desired older than age
AGE=60 # Age in days
if [[ -d "/home2/$CUSTOMER" ]]; then
    cd "/home2/$CUSTOMER"
    DEST="$DESTINATION_FOLDER"
    if [[ ! -d "$DEST" ]]; then
        mkdir -p $DEST
    fi
    TODAY=`date +%y%m%d`
    echo "Starting to move files to $DEST" > /root/logs/${TODAY}archive2log
    for DIRCONT in './'*; do
        echo "$DIRCONT moving to dataoffload...."
        SECONDS=$(($AGE * 3600 * 24)) # Turns days to seconds
        FILEAGE=$((`date +%s` - `date -r "$DIRCONT" +%s`))
        if [ $SECONDS -lt $FILEAGE ]; then 
            cp -r '$DIRCONT' $DEST >> /root/logs/${TODAY}archive2log
            if [[ -f '/mnt/dataoffload/$CUSTOMER/$DIRCONT' ]]; then
                echo "File $DIRCONT would have been removed"  #For testing only
                #rm --force $DIRCONT >> /root/logs/${`date +%D`}archive2log
            fi
        fi
    done
    echo "All files move to $2."
fi
```

And the results is:

```
cp:  cannot stat '$DIRCONT':  No such file or directory
```

Yet when I do an `ls` command it is there, and more importantly, if I do the command `cp -r <filelocation/filename> <destination/>` then it works fine.  Further, if I issue a `pwd` in the script, it shows it to be sitting in the correct directory, and the echo line returns the correct file/directory name(s) so I really don't see why it is not able to stat the file or directory.

I believe my problem most likely is in the line for loop line, but the output seems correct.  Before I put the single quote around the `./` part, it seemed to work as long as there were no spaces in the file names; however, if there were spaces, it would parse out each word and try it as a separate file.  The single quotes as shown returns everything properly, but none of it works, so I am not sure if this is progress or congress ;)

Can anyone explain why, or, (perhaps) more importantly tell me how to fix the code?

Comment: Why not using something like `rsync`?

Comment: Thank you for the rsync option, I was only peripherally aware of it and didn't know it could possibly do something on an age basis such as this.  Searching the web didn't turn up that as a suggested option before either, so I frankly didn't think about it.  

I do question why it is marked as a duplicate though.  As written right in the original question, I DID do a search before asking (and linked to what I found) and they did not fully explain it which is why I asked this.  At very least, explain how that linked article would have answered my question as I have read it and still don't see it

Comment: The problem with your script is that you put `$DIRCONT` in single quotes, not double quotes. As explained in the linked article, The difference between single and double quotes is that variables are only expanded in double quotes.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it more fully.  You were correct.  That fixed the issue.  Though I was surprised because it showed correctly expanded when I did the pwd command.  That is why I wasn't looking at that as the solution - I *thought* I had already verified it was expanding correctly.  Obviously I was wrong.  Looking back, I can now see how it iterated through the correct locations (why I thought it was expanding correctly); it was only the cp and if loop that were incorrectly quoted and therefore skipped.  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Also, if you want to add that as an answer, I can mark it as answered.  (or perhaps the duplicate is enough).

Comment: It's not possible to add an answer to a closed question.